# Youtube Video start time in iframe tag

Tags: html, flask, iframe, youtube, jinja2

I'm returning a list of dictionaries in flask : `return  render_template( "index.html" ,  data = data  )`

and then in **index.html** i loop throgh this list of dictionaries like this

```
{%for record in data%}
<p>{{record.video_id}} {{record.start_time}}</p>
{%endfor%}
```

i used iframe in html to preview the videos and at a specific start_time like this

```
{%for record in data%}
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{record.video_id}}?start={{record.start_time}}">
</iframe>

{%endfor%}
```

It shows the videos right but the start time is not so **how to enable starting video at the time of the start_time variable i gave ?**

Comment: `It shows the videos right but the start time is not` = [edit] your question with samples.

Answer (score 0):

Your link generator is incorrect use this pattern for URL `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{record.video_id}}?t={{record.start_time}}m{{record.start_time}}s">`

Comment: sorry for confused you, I tried this one and worked, src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jRzPsloTDR4?start=399"
start time calculate by minutes of video multiple by 60 seconds ,
but short answer is open your video in Youtube and click on share button, it give you link with specific start time